# Shell Script to Parse text into two separate strings

Tags: string, shell, parsing, wit.ai

My goal is to use a shell file to parse text from wit.ai and I cannot seem to get it right because the string (named `data`) can be vastly different. I've been trying to use a sed command but no luck. The response from the sever looks like this (but keep in mind it could be different in size):

```
data=
    {"status":"ok"}{"_text":"testing","msg_id":"56a26ccf-f324-455f-ba9b-db21c8c7ed50","outcomes":[{"_text":"testing","confidence":0.289,"entities":{},"intent":"weather"}]}
```

I would like to parse into two strings named `text` and `intent`.

The desired result should be two strings as follows

```
text=      "testing"
intent=     "weather"
```

The code I have thus far is:

```
data='{"status":"ok"}{"_text":"testing","msg_id":"56a26ccf-f324-455f-ba9b-db21c8c7ed50","outcomes":[{"_text":"testing","confidence":0.289,"entities":{},"intent":"weather"}$
text=$(echo $data | cut -d"," -f1 )     #removes text down to testing but leaves a quote at the end
text=$(echo "${text::-1}")              # this line removes the quote
echo $data
echo $text
```

The current result is:
`{"status":"ok"}{"_text":"testing`

I am close I just need to remove `{"status":"ok"}{"_text":"` so I am left with `testing`. I am close but I cant figure this last part out.

Comment: Is that the first or second `text`? What does your sed command look like?

Comment: What does that data *mean*? How is it to be interpreted? In what ways can/does it vary between responses? `"_text":"testing"` is in there twice. How do those two instances differ?

Comment: The occurrences of `"_text":"testing"` never differ from each other.

Comment: And it's `_text`, but you want `text`? What about the spacing of the output? (You see, this could do with a little more detail. And your efforts so far.)

Comment: Updated with the code that I currently have. Sorry I am a newb! :(

Comment: Are you sure this is not pure json? Are you sure your data string is correct? Are you going to parse a json string in shellscript?

Comment: Hello @dAm2k, yes it is JSON. I am using this on a Raspberry pi and I am not familiar with JSON or java at all so I figured I would use the script to parse the data seeing as I have to use a script to acquire the data in the first place. That being said, is this a horrible way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to deal with JSON is to use a parser. There are tons of options, for example:

- [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), the "grep, sed & awk for JSON"
- [`JSON.sh`](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh), a parser written in Bash (and officially recommended on www.json.org)
- [`json_pp`](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-PP-2.27103/bin/json_pp), a pretty printer in Perl

The problem with all these and your `data` is that they complain that it is malformed; if they *would* work, you could query your data directly, as demonstrated in all the tutorials of above linked tools.

Since you can't, we're back to fiddling around with the text directly. We could extract the data of interest with `grep -o`, which return only what it matches:

```
$ grep -o -e '"_text":"[^"]*"' -e '"intent":"[^"]*"'<<< "$data"
"_text":"testing"
"_text":"testing"
"intent":"weather"
```

The regex bit `"[^"]*"` means "a quote, then zero or more non-quotes, then another quote" – a way to match everything between two quotes, non-greedily.

To process this further, we can get rid of the duplicate line with `uniq`, then use sed to remove the quotes and underscores and finally replace the colons with equals signs and a tab:

```
$ grep -o -e '"_text":"[^"]*"' -e '"intent":"[^"]*"'<<< "$data" |
uniq | sed -r 's/"_?(.*)":(.*)/\1=\t\2/'
text=   "testing"
intent= "weather"
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay it's not exactly elegant but this seems to work

```
data='{"status":"ok"}{"_text":"testing","msg_id":"56a26ccf-f324-455f-ba9b-db21c8c7ed50","outcomes":[{"_text":"testing","confidence":0.289,"entities":{},"intent":"weather"}$
text=$(echo $data | cut -d"," -f1 )     #removes text down to testing but leaves a quote at the end
text=$(echo "${text::-1}")              # this line removes the quote
text=$(echo $text | cut -d"_" -f2 )     # removes beginning but still leaves "text":""
text=$(echo $text | cut -d":" -f2 )     # removes beginning but still leaves """ atr the beginning
text=$(echo ${text:1} )
echo $data
echo $text
```